# Apply function/for loop for subsetting data in R shiny

Tags: r, loops, split, shiny, subset

My overall goal is to have two multiple selectizeInputs that subsets a dataframe.  The first selectizeInput choose column names, and the second selectizeInput picks the values in the selected columns.  However, what I have now does not let you pick multiple columns names.  I also am not sure how to count the split dataframe in shiny.

Let's use the data df<-mpg. My main objective is to find the count (nrows) of the user section based off 'manufacturer'. So I want to select the column names: 'model' and 'display'.  I then want to select the values of 'sonata' and '2.4'.  Once selected, how many 'sonata' AND '2.4' values are in the 'hyundai', and then'jeep', and ect.

```
library(shiny)

df<-mpg

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(column (12,

  uiOutput("limitedresults2"), 
  uiOutput("variants2"), 
  uiOutput("whatwaschoosen"),
  tableOutput("content")

  ))))




server<- shinyServer (function(input, output) {

  output$limitedresults2 <-renderUI({ 
    list (titlePanel("Select Data :"),
          selectizeInput(
            'choose_columns2', '', choices =  names(df), multiple =TRUE,
            options = list(
              placeholder = 'Please select Attribute(s)',
              onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
            )))
  }) 

  dat<-reactive({
    sapply(df[,input$choose_columns2], unique)
  })

  output$variants2 <- renderUI({ 
    list (selectizeInput ('further', 
                          list('Choose Attribute(s) Value(s)', helpText("If you selected a variable that does not have more than one unique value, then the value will just appear as the name.")),
                          choices=dat(), 
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(
                            placeholder = 'Please select Value(s) of Attribute(s)',
                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))) ,
          p(""))  
  })  

  output$whatwaschoosen<-renderTable({
    Attribute<-input$choose_columns2
    Value<-input$further
    data.frame(Attribute,Value)
  }) 



  output$content <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$choose_columns2))
      return()

    df1<-as.data.frame(df[input$choose_columns2])
    subsetdf<-df1[ which(df1==input$further), ]
    needssplit<-subset(df, df1==subsetdf )
    (split( needssplit , needssplit$manufacturer ) ) ## if comment out this line.. a data table will appear.. 
  })




})  #end server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The result of split is a `list`, so you cannot use it in `renderTable`